# "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-arrayadapter

I basically know where this exception comes from and what causes it. It's because my textview is wrapped in an RelativeLayout.

But can you tell me why this works

```
playerAdapter = new PlayerAdapter(this,R.layout.item_lv_player,playerList);
lvPlayer.setAdapter(playerAdapter);
```

While this doesn't

```
PlayerAdapter playerAdapter1 = new PlayerAdapter(this,R.layout.item_lv_player,playerAdapterSource[0]);
spinnerPlayer1.setAdapter(playerAdapter1);
```

Shouldn't both of this throw an exception?
PlayerAdapater is a class that extends ArrayAdapter.

Is it because in the first example I'm using a ListView, and in the second one it's a Spinner? That wouldn't sound logical to me at all since the problem is the creation of the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

exception is not depends upon your adapter,its depends upon widgets.Every widgets has some properties,based on that only it will raise a exception,

Listview always depends upon Textview for all positions,but spinner not depending on that.If you run ListView without R.id.TextView it raise a nullpointer exception because of you have not initialized the textview in the adapter.But spinner doesnot because it not depending on the textview.

Comment: I know that's a way to fix it. But I'm confused while one example throws an exception, and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have ArrayAdapter with 3 parameters passed to it.

The 3 parameter ArrayAdapter constructor can take any of the following parameters -

```
1) ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)

2) ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

**The first one Explanation -**

- > public **ArrayAdapter** (Context context, int resource, int
  >   textViewResourceId)
  >
  > Added in API level 1 Constructor
  >
  > **Parameters**
  >
  > *context*  The current context.
  >
  > *resource* The resource ID for a  layout file containing a layout to
  >   use when instantiating views.
  >
  > *textViewResourceId*   The id of the TextView within the layout
  >   resource  to be populated

**The second one Explanation -**

- > public **ArrayAdapter** (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
  >
  > Added in API level 1 Constructor
  >
  > **Parameters**
  >
  > *context*   The current context.
  >
  > *resource*  The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.
  >
  > *objects*   The objects to represent in the ListView.

Having explained that for -

```
PlayerAdapter playerAdapter1 = new PlayerAdapter(this,
R.layout.item_lv_player,playerAdapterSource[0]);
spinnerPlayer1.setAdapter(playerAdapter1);
```

1. Is the last parameter a textViewResourceId ? > NO
2. Is the last parameter a ListView ? > NO

From developer docs [android ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).